# Is it possible to create ostream object, which outputs to multiple destinations?

Tags: c++, oop, boost, stl, iostream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I compose output streams, so output goes multiple places at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760726/how-can-i-compose-output-streams-so-output-goes-multiple-places-at-once)

In 0-th approximation I have a class

```
class MyClass{
public:
   ...
   std::ostream & getOStream(){return f;}
private:
   ofstream f;
   ...
};
```

Which is used sometimes in the following way:

```
MyClass myclass;
myclass.getOStream()<<some<<information<<printed<<here;
```

But now I want to change the class MyClass, so that information will be printed both to f and to std::out, i.e. I want the above line to be equivalent to

```
myclass.f<<some<<information<<printed<<here;
std::cout<<some<<information<<printed<<here;
```

I don't know any good way to do that. Do you? Is there any standard solution (for example in stl or in boost)?

P.S.
I tried to search on this, but it seems that I don't know good keywords. Words `multiple`, `output`, `ostream`, `C++`, `boost` seem to be too general.

Comment: You could write your own ostream class but the problem with that is you need to write it.