# C++: How do I print to ostream on both a file and the console within the same method where a file is being passed as an ostream object

Tags: c++, cout

```
void method(std::ostream &output){
     cout << "some text";
}

int main(){
      method(std::cout);
}
```

This gets added to my file when I run my program like this
     ./program arg > file.txt

How can I run this program so that this prints out to the file but also has separate printing for the console?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8220956/596781) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1760726/596781).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (non-)answer is not to bother inside your own program, but instead use a dedicated tool like `tee`:

```
./program arg | tee file.txt
```

If you want something finer-grained, you'll need to build in some equivalent logic into your program, e.g. using [Boost tee](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/iostreams/tee.hpp).

Comment: On windows there is http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm which has tee for windows.

Comment: Thank you. I need to print different output to the console than to the file so boost tee is probably the way to go.