# How to "parametrize" an output stream?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, fstream, ostream

How can I make this pseudo-code work?

```
std::ostream  ostr;
std::ofstream ofstr;

if(condition) {
    ostr = std::cout;
}
else {
    ofstr.open("file.txt");
    ostr = ofstr;
}

ostr << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

This does not compile, since `std::ostream` does not have a public default constructor.

Comment: The linked question isn't an _exact_ duplicate, but it's close enough, and the accepted answer shows a solution for your problem.

Comment: In your case you may use ternary operator: `std::ostream& ostr = (condition ? std::cout : (ofstr.open("file.txt"), ofstr));`

Comment: @Jarod42: just tried; it works when `condition` is true, and I get the output on cout, but I get no file written when `condition` is false.

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/988e1cce31480232).

Comment: To send data to multiple streams simultaneously: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760726/how-can-i-compose-output-streams-so-output-goes-multiple-places-at-once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760726/how-can-i-compose-output-streams-so-output-goes-multiple-places-at-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you may use ternary operator:

```
std::ostream& ostr = (condition ?
                      std::cout :
                      (ofstr.open("file.txt"), ofstr)); // Comma operator also used
                                                        // To allow fstream initialization.
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation can switch to other streams:

```
std::ofstream ofstr;
std::ostream *ostr;

ofstr.open("file.txt");

ostr = &ofstr;
*ostr << "test --> file\n" << std::endl;

ostr = &std::cout;
*ostr << "test --> stdout\n" << std::endl;
```